# How to use VariableRef as indices in Julia JuMP

Tags: julia, julia-jump

In Julia when I do:

```
model = Model();
set_optimizer(model, Cbc.Optimizer);

N=11;

model = Model();
set_optimizer(model, Cbc.Optimizer);
@variable(model, X[1:N,1:N,1:N], Bin);
@variable(model, 1<=K<=10, Int);

for k in K
    @constraint(model, (sum(X[1,j,k] for j= 1:N)) ==1 )
end
```

I get this error:

> ArgumentError: invalid index: K of type VariableRef

Because I used a variable `reference(k)` as index for a vector (`X`).

How could I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `K` to interact with other variables you need to make it a binary vector with the sum of `1` and then use multiplication for modelling the interaction.

```
@variable(model, K[1:10], Bin);
@constraint(model, sum(K) == 1)
```

Now I am not exactly shure what you want to accomplish. If you want to turn off and on equations depending on the value of `K` this would look like this:

```
@constraint(model,con[k in 1:10], sum(X[1,j,k] for j= 1:N)*K[k] == K[k] )
```

This however makes the model non-linear and you would need to use a non-linear solver for it.
Depending on your use case having sums simply up to `1` could be enough (and this yields a model much easier for solvers but might your business needs or not):

```
@constraint(model,con[k in 1:10], sum(X[1,j,k] for j= 1:N) == K[k] )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I want to solve a classic vehicle routing problem. K is the number of vehicles (routes). The objective is to minimize  K.
In this FOR statement (in the question) I wanted to use the amount of variable K as an index.

Comment: And another question, howis it possible to use condition (if then) statement for constraints?

Comment: For TSP look at the great book "Julia Programming for Operations Research, 2nd Edition". Heuristics work here well - try  the package TravellingSalesmenHeuristics.jl

Comment: You can build `IF` conditions via binary variables - very similarly to the way I have shown you.